# Merge, Unmerge, Remerge macro

Tags: vba, excel, merge

I am working on a macro to unmerge merged cells in a given range and then re merge the original merged cells which were unmerged. I have been struggling to identify how to store a list of the cells which are initially unmerged so that the macro can re merge those exact cells.The rows that are merged in the spreadsheet change from week to week.

```
Sub MergeUnmerge()

'

Mergeunmerge Macro
'

Dim mergelist As Range

Dim celllist As Range


For Each cell In Range("A1:S49")

If cell.MergeCells = True Then
   Set mergelist = celllist
            cell.UnMerge
        End If
    Next

 For Each cell In mergelist
    Range("celllist").Merge
Next
```

End Sub

Comment: You should consider using collections or arrays to store your information, so they can be processed once you have completed your primary task. i.e. add the address of each merged area (Range.MergeArea.Address) to a collection then you can unmerge all cells, complete tasks then merge the cells for each item in the collection

Comment: I edited my answer with a tested working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to:

- use `mergeCells` property to check for merged cells
- use Areas property of `Range` object
- use `Merge` method to merge areas back

like follows

```
Option Explicit

Sub MergeUnmerge()
    Dim mergedCells As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    With Range("A1:S49") '<--| reference your range
        Set mergedCells = .Offset(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Resize(1, 1) '<--| initialize mergedCells range to a spurious cell out of referenced range
        For Each cell In .Cells '<--|loop through referenced range cells
            If cell.mergeCells Then '<--| if current cell belongs to a merged area
                Set mergedCells = Union(mergedCells, cell.MergeArea) '<--| update 'mergedCells' range
                cell.UnMerge '<--| unmerge it
            End If
        Next

        Set mergedCells = Intersect(mergedCells, .Cells) '<--| filter out the spurious cell
        If Not mergedCells Is Nothing Then '<--| if there's some cell left
            For Each cell In mergedCells.Areas '<--| loop through areas
                cell.Merge '<--| merge curent area
            Next
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to add the `MergeArea` address to an array.

```
Sub MergeUnmerge()

Dim cel As Range
Dim mergeArr()  
y = 0

For Each cel In Range("A1:S49")
    If cel.MergeCells = True Then
        ReDim Preserve mergeArr(y + 1)
        mergeArr(y + 1) = cel.MergeArea.Address
        cel.UnMerge
        y = y + 1
    End If
Next cel

For x = 1 To y
    Range(mergeArr(x)).Merge
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: I'd make that more generic and intake a `Range` parameter, and declare the `mergeArr()` outside the loop and `If` block for readability. Declaring variables close to usage is a very good idea, but not when the code (momentarily) confusing ;-)

Comment: Dropped that If completely @Mat'sMug